# why does deleting printf function causes a SIGBUS error?

Tags: c, pointers

Im kinda new to C and I was trying to make a something like a malloc function just to practice pointers and all that stuff. everything worked fine but when I deleted `printf` functions in my main functions it returned SIGBUG error. from what I have read SIGBUS error is when processor tries to read from or write to memory that is not physically avaivable and I dont know what this have to do with deleting printf functions. I also tried the same code on other C and C++ compilers and it worked just fine without any errors.

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define heap_size 4096
#define m_availble 0x00
#define m_allocated 0x01
#define m_freed 0x02

typedef unsigned int uint;

char heap[heap_size]; //memory for Alloc function

void* Alloc(uint size);
void StoreInt(uint position, int value);
int GetInt(uint position);
void ShowHeap(uint position);

int main()
{
    int* MyPtr = (int*)Alloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    MyPtr[0] = 69420;
    //printf("myptr adr1: %p\n", &MyPtr[1]);
    MyPtr[1] = 6;
    //printf("myptr adr2: %p\n", &MyPtr[2]);
    MyPtr[2] = 11;

    ShowHeap(0);
}

void* Alloc(uint size) //allocates memory inside heap
{
    uint position = 0;
    size += sizeof(int) + sizeof(char);
    
    while(position + size + 40 < heap_size )
    {
        if(heap[position] == m_availble)
        {
            /*m_availble means it can store memory at this position*/
            
            heap[position] = m_allocated;
            /*m_allocated means memory at this is position
            is allocated*/
            
            StoreInt(position + 1, size);
            /*stores the size requied by user*/
            
            return &heap[(position + sizeof(int) +
                          sizeof(char))];
            /*returns pointer to adress that the user
            can write to or read from*/
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void StoreInt(uint position, int value)
{
    /*stores valeu in to the heap*/
    
    int* ptr = (int*)&heap[position];
    ptr[0] = value;
}

int GetInt(uint position)
{
    /*returns value from the heap*/
    
    int* ptr = (int*)&heap[position];
    return ptr[0];
}

void ShowHeap(uint position)
{
    /*display adresses with values stored at those
      adresses*/
    
    printf("HEAP:\n");
    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
    {
        printf("adr: %p - ", &heap[position
                                 + y * 4]);
            
        for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            printf("%i, ", heap[position + 4 * y + x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not `SIGBUS`?

Comment: Most datatypes have alignment requirements. I don't think your allocator ensures that the data will be properly aligned.

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger - it will help you figure out exactly what the problem is. Instead of staring at the program and trying to spot a problem, you can actually look at the running program at the exact moment it crashes.

Comment: If adding/deleting printf affets the behavior, it usually means you have undefined behavior somewhere. It's just a concidence that the symptom changes due to the printf.

Comment: Your `while` loop looks like an infinite loop. If the `if` condition is not true, it never updates any of the variables, so it will keep testing the same position.

Comment: I don't see how you prevent overlapping allocations. Couldn't `heap[position]` be in the middle of some previous allocation, and contain `m_available`?

Comment: You have an alignment problem.  Try changing your code to align integers on a multiple of their size.  You should also declare your heap array to have the most restrictive alignment type.  You can't assume that a `char` array will be aligned on an integer boundary.

Comment: When showing heap contents you should show available/allocate indicators, size allocated, data : this would enable you to see more clearly what’s inside and how your code is supposed to handle it.

Comment: while loop inside my alloc functioin is not done yet i will be adding more if statements later like jump to another postion if this is allocated

Comment: @PtitXav Im using ShowHeap function to print part of my memory and everythink works as it should.

Comment: Compile your code with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) used as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Add also calls to [fflush](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html). Consider using [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)

Comment: zmouch,  "adresses" --> "addresses".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Alignment**

If the alignment is not correct the below is *undefined behavior* and may cause a bus fault.

```
char heap[heap_size]; //memory for Alloc function

// StoreInt()
void StoreInt(uint position, int value) {
  int* ptr = (int*)&heap[position];
  ptr[0] = value;

// GetInt()
  int* ptr = (int*)&heap[position];
  return ptr[0];
```

Alternative, use `memcpy()`:

```
// StoreInt()
void StoreInt(uint position, int value) {
  memcpy(&heap[position], &value, sizeof value);

// GetInt()
  int x;
  memcpy(&x, &heap[position], sizeof x);
  return x;
```

> I also tried the same code on other C and C++ compilers and it worked just fine without any errors.

Other compilers may have different alignment requirements for types like `int`.

---

**Casting**

Casting is a whiff of [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).  Cast is only sporadically needed in C.  In OP's code, all the casts *smell*.

---

**`char` may be *signed***

Likely more informative output in `ShowHeap()` had `heap[]` been `unsigned char` than `char`.

Really want negative output -128 to 127 from `printf("%i, ", heap[position + 4 * y + x]);` or 0 to 255?

Answer (score 1):

A `SIGBUS` exception is normally thrown on bus alignment problems.  The implementation of `malloc()` memory management has to align the returned pointers to the largest alignment possible, in order to make the pointers returned to be properly aligned with any kind of data.  I had this problem in the past, and it can affect anywhere you use the pointer (and this includes `printf` of course).

Be careful when implementing a memory allocator.